# Once horizontal scroll reaches endpoint, is it possible to automatically restart at the beginning, essentially creating a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Grid set up in CSS with multiple div's placed in a horizontal scroll bar.  I'd like the scroll bar to restart back at the original div once it's reaches the end, essentially creating loop.  Looking to avoid doing it with Javascript.

```css
.scrollBottomList {
    grid-area: scrollBottomList;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 15%); /*percentages adjust to the screen size*/
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'column1 column2 column3'
    'column1 column2 column3'
    'column1 column2 column3';
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
                <div class="scrollBottomList">
                <div class="column1">1</div>
                <div class="column2">2</div>
                <div class="column3">3</div>
                <div class="column4">4</div>
                <div class="column5">5</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Without JS, don't think so

Comment: Here's CodePen with a solution to your question but with JS of course: https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj